# Name for soldering a PCB orthogonally into another? Vertical castellation?

Tags: pcb, production

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri4pG.png]
(image stolen from [OK to connect boards perpendicularly like this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/ok-to-connect-boards-perpendicularly-like-this))

Is there a name for the production method where say a base board (horizontal) has a slot milled into it with the solder mask open around it, most often the soldermask is split into several sections to give several electrical nets, and another PCB with an mechanically suiable edge connector inserted orthogonally (vertical) and soldered in place?

Heck, I even put a board like this into mass production for a previous company, but I can't find a name for it and hence no pictures on google to show what I mean.

Is there a name for this? It's similar to stacking a module on top of a base PCB in castellation mountng, but vertical castellation didn't give any good results. Think PCI without the PCI connector and permanent installation.

EDIT: Suggestions form colleagues:

- tongue and groove
- mortise and tenon

Comment: I know what you are talking about as I have actually done a few boards like it at my work. I didn't know it actually had a name though?

Comment: I found [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/ok-to-connect-boards-perpendicularly-like-this) but scanning over it and the answers, there is no "this method is called that" mentioned :-/

Comment: @MCG and/or Arsenal A picture is good enough at this moment. "pseudo-connector" in Arsenals link is closest so far!

Comment: Castellation strictly doesn't refer to the method of mounting but the shape of the mounted board (specifically, the cut through-holes on its border). I'm not sure if that's why you had trouble finding it, but maybe?

Comment: @Hearth Sadly no, I'm looking for the opposite, protruding edge connector on the daughterboard instead of cut though-holes.

Comment: @winny Which is why I think "vertical castellation" may not have turned up many results.

Comment: @Hearth Which is why I'm asking :-)

Answer (score 4):

I have found this on the [Yokogawa website](https://www.yokogawa.com/au/library/resources/yokogawa-technical-reports/ut100-series-of-temperature-controllers/) where they just call it direct soldering:

[image: Figure 7 Structure of UT130]

My Google-fu isn't very strong with this one. "PCB perpendicular soldering" turned up one other picture from a DIY site.